# Replace tags with inner text

Tags: .net, string

I have `string`, that represents HTML and I need to replace in it all the `<a {attributes here}>Inner Text</a>` with `Inner Text`. How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written by svick, use http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/. If what you have is an XML (so all the tags are closed...) you can use the various Xml libraries of C#. Don't use Regexes unless you are REALLY sure of the EXACT format of your html (for example if it's machine generated) otherwise... [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do exactly that, dropping `<a ...>` tags you could use a regexp to drop it. If it is any more complex than that, you need something more powerful than regexpes as they cannot handle nested tags.

Comment: @xanatos: It is fairly safe to assume that `<a>` tags are not nested and then it should be safe to use a regexp. That's why I wrote that if it is any more complex you need something more powerful.